# How to get 100k ether in testrpc?

Tags: truffle, testrpc

Id like to run some unit tests in truffle with huge sums of ether (over 30k ether), but my default accounts only seem to have 100 ether in them. 
Does anyone know how to increase this?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to change the settings so that when I run truffle test it uses the bigger eth amount? its just annoying to run a separate testrpc instance

Comment: You can use ganache-cli as a [web3 provider](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli#library) in your tests, that way you can launch your own instance and adjust the balance per test.